# To delete a row when sysdate is a certain value in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having a problem deleting a row in my table after it has existed for a certain amount of time. To be more specific, I have a column named 'hiredate' and I want to delete a row when the hiredate of that row is older than 5 years.

Comment: What have you tried?  What was the error?  Why is there a trigger tag on this question?  Deleting data isn't something one would normally do in a trigger.

Comment: There is a trigger tag because I'm assuming I will need one because I'm not deleting the row at the time of writing the code.

Comment: Sounds more like you'll need a stored proc that handles the deletion of the data, and then a job which runs periodically (eg. daily/weekly/monthly etc) and calls the stored proc. Which bit are you having an issue with?

Comment: I only have the part to delete the row when it gets to the rerquired time: 

delete from emp
where p_id = (select p_id from emp where sysdate = hiredate+1825);

Comment: Surely that would be much better written as: `delete from emp where hiredate <= add_months(trunc(sysdate), -5*12);` to take account of rows that haven't been deleted yet but are older than 5 years ago? Stick that into a stored proc and then use `dbms_scheduler.create_job` to create a job that will run the stored proc at your specified interval.

Answer (score 4):

With respect to the code you have in your comment:

```
delete from emp where p_id = (select p_id from emp where sysdate = hiredate+1825);
```

It's totally unnecessary to use a subquery here. You could simply do:

```
DELETE FROM emp WHERE sysdate = hiredate + 1825;
```

Of course, that will only work where the time portion of `hiredate` is exactly equal to the time portion of `SYSDATE`! Also, `1825` is not five years; it is five times 365. A better way of doing this in Oracle would be:

```
DELETE FROM emp
 WHERE hiredate < TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -60));
```

or, if you're certain you want to delete only one day's results:

```
DELETE FROM emp
 WHERE hiredate >= TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -60)) - 1
   AND hiredate < TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -60));
```

However, if you're running this as a one-time query or even as a scheduled job, you'll want to delete everything over five years of age; a scheduled job, for example, could always fail one night and succeed the next, leaving you with an odd day's records in `EMP`.

By the way, `ADD_MONTHS()` is the safest way of adding or subtracting years in Oracle; using year to month intervals can fail during leap years. For example, the following would fail on February 29, 2016:

```
DELETE FROM emp
 WHERE hiredate < TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '5' YEAR;
```

The right side of the equation would calculate to a date of February 29, 2011, which doesn't exist.